# Changing Link color on div hover when div is separate and nested

Tags: css, hyperlink, nested-sets, onhover

I have 12 links on the left side of my page that anchors to 12 divs on the right side of the page. Whenever I scroll down I want the color of the links to change on div hover.

Problem: 1.) The 12 links are in a nested div 2.) the divs on the right are in a separate nested div that come AFTER the links.

I tried using this code: http://jsfiddle.net/gU4sw/7/ but then switched back because it wasn't working with the nested divs.

Is there a way to solve this? Here is what I have so far. I haven't inserted all the divs yet because I am waiting to solve this problem first.

HTML:

```
<body>
<body style="margin:0px;">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navbar">
        <div id="navbartext">
            <div class="center">
                <div id="morning"><a href="index.html">MORNING</a></div><br/>
                <div id="one"><a href="#7:30">7:30</a></div><br/>
                <div id="two"><a href="#8:00">8:00</a></div><br/>
                <div id="three"><a href="#10:00">10:00</a></div><br/>
                <div id="noon"><a href="#NOON">NOON</a></div><br/>
                <div id="five"><a href="#2:00">2:00</a></div><br/>
                <div id="six"><a href="#5:00">5:00</a></div><br/>
                <div id="seven"><a href="#5:15">5:15</a></div><br/>
                <div id="night"><a href="#NIGHT">NIGHT</a></div><br/>
                <div id="nine"><a href="#9:00">9:00</a></div><br/>
                <div id="ten"><a href="#12:00">12:00</a></div><br/>
                <div id="eleven"><a href="#3:00">3:00</a></div><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
     <div id="subcontent">
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><img src="images/myday.png" width="613" height="287" /> <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <h5>&#8595;SCROLL DOWN&#8595;</h5><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

                <a name="7:30"><div class="img"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="640" height="" /></div></a>
                <a name="9:00"><div class="img"><img src="img.jpeg" width="640" height="" /></div></a>
     </div>
</div>

</body>


</body>
</html>
```

CSS:
    $0@charset "UTF-8";
    /* CSS Document */

```
#wrapper {margin: 0px;}

/*Navigation Bar*/
#navbar {background:#FF9999; 
    padding:15px; 
    position:fixed; 
    left: 90px;
    width:115px; 
    height:100%;}
#navbartext { top: 50%;
    width: 115px;
    height: 100%;}

a:link {color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {color: #FFf;}
a:active {color: #FFf58A;}
a:hover {color: #FFF58A;}
img:hover + a  {color: #FFF58A;}

.center {display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #FF9999;
    width: 115px;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;}

#morning {width:115px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%}    
#one {width:115px; 
    top: 11%; 
    position: absolute;}
#two {width:115px; 
    top: 19.4%; 
    position: absolute;}
#three {width:115px; 
    top: 27%;
    position: absolute;}
#noon {width:115px;
    top: 35%;
    position: absolute;}
#five {width:115px;
    top: 43%;
    position: absolute;}
#six {width:115px;
    top: 51%;
    position: absolute;}
#seven {width:115px;
    top: 59%;
    position: absolute;}
#night {width:115px;
    top: 67%;
    position: absolute;}
#nine {width:115px;
    top: 75%;
    position: absolute;}
#ten {width:115px;
    top: 83%;
    position: absolute;}
#eleven {width:115px;
    top: 91%;
    position:absolute;}




/*Content*/
#content {height: 10000px; 
    padding-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #cda8cb;}    
#subcontent {width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;}
.img {top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 950px;
    padding-top: 175px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    img: hover + a color: #FFF58A;}



/*text*/
<h4> {color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 260%;
    vertical-align: middle;}
<h5> {font-color: #cda8cb;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 260%;
    vertical-align: middle;}    


/* 
#content {height:10000px; 
    padding-top:45px;
    margin-left: 350px;}

#subcontent {width: 950px;
    height: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }
#navbartext {}
#navbartext {}
#myday {padding-top: 110px;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've really complicated things for yourself when you used `divs` instead of lists.

Still, if you want it that way, here's a solution. Add some `jQuery` code in your page that will take care of all those hover events. jQuery has a function `hover()` that calls your methods whenever there's a hover.

You can get to know more about the function here: http://api.jquery.com/hover/

After going through above, add this:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $("#IDofThediv").hover(
        function() {        //This will be executed when the mouse enters the div
            $("#IDofTheAnchor").css("color", "#000");
        },
        function() {        //This will be executed when the mouse exits the div
            $("#IDofTheAnchor").css("color", "#FFF");
        }
    );
});
```

Now, because your code uses anchors inside divs of navigation bar, and because you've specifically changed the anchors' css in your css file, you need to work on the anchors rather than the divs.

Let me know how it goes. :)

**EDIT:** And please remove `:`'s from your node IDs and Names, they are no good.

Comment: Why, what's wrong with the colons in the id and name attributes? They work fine, don't they? :confused:

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that, my point was, **-special characters should be ignored in ids & names-**, they create complications sometimes. @enhzflep

Comment: Here's an example for you @enhzflep, this one doesn't works because of the `:` in id, [not working](http://jsfiddle.net/AeSRM/), and this one does, because there is no `:` in the id, [works](http://jsfiddle.net/aLYAZ/).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I'll bite..

First, your css has an unclosed comment - that's nulling the effect of some of it. 
Next your h4 and h5 rules are wrong (remove the angled braces)

Finally, a little javascript will help do the job. Tested with chrome.
Enjoy!

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#wrapper {margin: 0px;}

/*Navigation Bar*/
#navbar {background:#FF9999; 
    padding:15px; 
    position:fixed; 
    left: 90px;
    width:115px; 
    height:100%;}
#navbartext { top: 50%;
    width: 115px;
    height: 100%;}

a:link {color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
    text-decoration: none;}
a:visited {color: #FFf;}
a:active {color: #FFf58A;}


.center {display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    background: #FF9999;
    width: 115px;
    color: #FFF;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px;}

#morning {width:115px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 3%}    
#one {width:115px; 
    top: 11%; 
    position: absolute;}
#two {width:115px; 
    top: 19.4%; 
    position: absolute;}
#three {width:115px; 
    top: 27%;
    position: absolute;}
#noon {width:115px;
    top: 35%;
    position: absolute;}
#five {width:115px;
    top: 43%;
    position: absolute;}
#six {width:115px;
    top: 51%;
    position: absolute;}
#seven {width:115px;
    top: 59%;
    position: absolute;}
#night {width:115px;
    top: 67%;
    position: absolute;}
#nine {width:115px;
    top: 75%;
    position: absolute;}
#ten {width:115px;
    top: 83%;
    position: absolute;}
#eleven {width:115px;
    top: 91%;
    position:absolute;}




/*Content*/
#content {height: 10000px; 
    padding-top: 45px;
    margin-left: 200px;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #cda8cb;}    
#subcontent {width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;}
.img {top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
    display: table-cell;
    margin: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 950px;
    padding-top: 175px;
    padding-bottom: 200px;
    img: hover + a color: #FFF58A;}



/*text*/
h4 {color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Quicksand', sans-serif;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 260%;
    vertical-align: middle;}
h5 {font-color: #cda8cb;
    font-size: 24px;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: 100;
    line-height: 260%;
    vertical-align: middle;}    


#content {height:10000px; 
    padding-top:45px;
    margin-left: 350px;}

#subcontent {width: 950px;
    height: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    }

#myday {padding-top: 110px;}

a:hover, .remoteControlled a
{
    color: #FFF58A;
}

</style>
<script>
function myMouseOver(element)
{
    var srchStr = element.getAttribute('name');
    var aList = document.getElementById('navbartext').getElementsByTagName('a');
    var i, n = aList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        curStr = aList[i].innerHTML
        //curStr = curStr.substr(1);
        if (curStr == srchStr)
            aList[i].parentNode.className = 'remoteControlled';
    }
}

function myMouseOut(element)
{
    var navList = document.getElementById('navbartext').getElementsByTagName('a');
    var i, n = navList.length;
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        navList[i].parentNode.className = '';
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<body style="margin:0px;">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="navbar">
        <div id="navbartext">
            <div class="center">
                <div id="morning"><a href="index.html">MORNING</a></div><br/>
                <div id="one"><a href="#7:30">7:30</a></div><br/>
                <div id="two"><a href="#8:00">8:00</a></div><br/>
                <div id="three"><a href="#10:00">10:00</a></div><br/>
                <div id="noon"><a href="#NOON">NOON</a></div><br/>
                <div id="five"><a href="#2:00">2:00</a></div><br/>
                <div id="six"><a href="#5:00">5:00</a></div><br/>
                <div id="seven"><a href="#5:15">5:15</a></div><br/>
                <div id="night"><a href="#NIGHT">NIGHT</a></div><br/>
                <div id="nine"><a href="#9:00">9:00</a></div><br/>
                <div id="ten"><a href="#12:00">12:00</a></div><br/>
                <div id="eleven"><a href="#3:00">3:00</a></div><br/>
          </div>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>

<div id="content">
     <div id="subcontent">
        <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><img src="images/myday.png" width="613" height="287" /> <br/><br/><br/><br/>
        <h5>&#8595;SCROLL DOWN&#8595;</h5><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>

                <a name="7:30" onmouseout='myMouseOut();' onmouseover='myMouseOver(this);'><div class="img"><img src="images/cal.gif" width="640" height="" /></div></a>
                <a name="9:00" onmouseout='myMouseOut();' onmouseover='myMouseOver(this);'><div class="img"><img src="img.jpeg" width="640" height="" /></div></a>
     </div>
</div>

</body>


</body>
</html>
```